# How should I use `sealed class` or `hashmap` or `enums` in a specific case?

Tags: kotlin, enums, sealed-class

I use sealed classes to distinguish normal functions from suspend functions.

```kotlin
sealed class Function {
  class SuspendFunction(val execute: suspend () -> Boolean) : Function() {
    suspend operator fun invoke() {
      execute()
    }
  }

  class NormalFunction(val execute: () -> Boolean) : Function() {
    operator fun invoke() {
      execute()
    }
  }
}
```

Then I need some data to display in the display layer, I use `enum.values()`.

```kotlin
enum class Work(val function: Function) {
  A(Function.SuspendFunction { true }),
  B(Function.NormalFunction { true })
}
```

Then I need to do various follow-up operations against `Work.function`.

```kotlin
fun run(work: Work) {
  when (work) {
    Work.A -> {
      work.function()
    }
    Work.B -> {
      
    }
  }
}
```

But this throws an error:

```
Expression 'function' of type 'Function' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

I think IDE no smart cast `Function` to `NormalFunction`.

This puts me in an embarrassing situation, I don't know how to choose to use `enum` or `sealed class` or `hashmap`.

1. In the current situation, I may only use `as` to manually modify the type, which is not elegant.
2. If I replace `enum` with `hashmap`, it should be able to solve the problem that the IDE cannot smart cast. But when using the `use` statement, it loses the characteristics of `enum` or `sealed class`.
3. If I use `sealed class` instead of `enum`, the sealed class cannot be traversed, that is, you cannot use it like this `enum.values()`.

What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: Why make it complicated? You could just exclusively use `suspend` functions for your tasks since you're going to have to launch coroutines anyway to be able to run the ones that are suspending.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Since `Work.function` may also not be a `suspend` function, there is no need to start a coroutine.

Comment: What I mean is, you’re adding a lot of complexity to only *sometimes* avoid starting a coroutine. Can’t you just launch coroutines for all of them?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, I can launch coroutines for all of them. But this brings up another question, will this have unexpected results? I don't know.

Comment: There can be unexpected results from coroutines if you aren't familiar with how they operate, but if that's the case, you'll have unexpected results for your suspend functions, too.

Comment: It won't make anything wrong if your code is already correct.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, but requires multiple use of `as`. or you mean use `suspend` function not make anything wrong?

Comment: I mean you should eliminate this whole thing and use suspend functions everywhere, as advised by @Tenfour04.

Comment: For example, eliminate the sealed class and change your enum to directly use suspend functions: `enum class Work(val function: suspend () -> Boolean) { ...` No need to overcomplicate.